# Operation not allowed: STORED BY hive on spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to achieve a connection between Hive and DynamoDB via Spark. 
For that I need to execute this code:

```
sparkSession.sql("create external table test (id string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES('dynamodb.table.name'='testdb','dynamodb.column.mapping'='id:id')")
```

But I am having an error:

```
ParseException: u"\nOperation not allowed: STORED BY(line 1, pos 111)
```

I read somewhere that `STORED BY` was not supported on Spark. Is there any alternative method? Is it always not supported? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from [Spark Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html):

> Note that, Hive storage handler is not supported yet when creating
>   table, you can create a table using storage handler at Hive side, and
>   use Spark SQL to read it.

As you can see, Spark cannot create Hive's `StorageHandler` tables, but can read already existing one.

The solution could be to create a table definition directly in Hive (using *beeline*, *hive* or any other JDBC client of your preference) and you will still be able to read the table in any Hive-enabled Spark (i.e., `spark.sql("select * from test")`).

Comment: Were you able to get this working outside EMR clusters? Reads from spark SQL still seem to be failing as mentioned in the issue https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/issues/50